# Map reduce problem in python

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce

I am currently struggling with an assignment. The solution would input a txt file and run through counting the number of palindromes and their frequency. I need to use Map reduce to create to do so

For example: the string "bab bab bab cab cac dad" would output:

```
bab 3
cab 1
dad 1
```

Here is what I have so far

```
def palindrome(string):
    palindromes = []
    for word in string.split(" "):
        if (word == word[::-1]):
            palindromes.append(word)
    return palindromes 

string = "abc abd bab tab cab tat yay uaefdfdu"
print map(lambda x: palindrome(x), ["bab abc dab bab bab dad crap pap pap "])
```

Currently prints

```
[['bab', 'bab', 'bab', 'dad', 'pap', 'pap', '']]
```

Here is my attempt so far at the reduce section

```
def p(lists):
for list in lists:

set_h = set(list) 

return set_h
```

with the p function I want to create a set of all palindromes found. Then run a count of the palindromes on the list and make a dict out of this

```
print reduce(p, [['bab', 'bab', 'bab', 'dad', 'pap', 'pap', '']])
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: It's "palindrome"... I fixed the spelling and cleaned up the formatting.

Comment: Should be tagged with `homework`

Comment: FYI, map(lambda x: palindrome(x), ...) is redundant. You can just as easily do map(palindrome, ...) and get the same results. However, you should probably also re-think your palindrome() function to operate on only a single item at a time, and split your input in advance. Also remember that you will need to have the results sorted between the map and reduce steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split your string into a list *before* you map it.  **map()** is for lists, sets, and dicts, *not* strings.

```
word_list = words_str.split(" ")
```

Avoid using *map-filter-reduce* unless your assignment dictates it; [GVR](http://www.python.org/~guido/) [says so](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).  The proper solution uses Python's [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) syntax.  In fact, you can do it with a pretty nasty one-liner:

```
pal_count = {
    x: word_list.count(x)  # reduce-ish
    for x in word_list     # map-ish
    if x == x[::-1]        # filter-ish
    }
for x, y in pal_count.iteritems():
    print x, y             # print the results!
```

Breaking it down...

1. Catch this in a dictionary object to print it later: `pal_count = {`
2. Define the return objects: `x: word_list.count(x)`  We use key:value syntax to associate the palindrome, *x*, with its number of occurrences.  **[count()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)** is like a built-in reduce function for lists.
3. Iterate through our list with a **for loop**, assigning the current value to 'x': `for x in word_list`
4. We only want to return palindromes, so we add a comparison operator to *filter* out bad values: `if x == x[::-1] # cool logic, btw`
5. Hurray! `}`

By the way, I'm only doing your homework because I never did mine.

The slower, less flexible, less portable, less *awesome* equivalent uses nested for loops:

```
pal_count = dict()
for x in word_list:                     # same loop
    if x == x[::-1]                     # is this a palindrome?
        if x in pal_count:              # have we seen before?
            pal_count[x] += 1
        else:                           # this one is new!
            pal_count.setdefault(x, 1)
```

Comment: It's not cool to provide complete working solutions to problems marked as homework or assignments. Not sure why you consider the second version to be slower. Calling `.count()` on large datasets is not the fastest thing on earth, especially if you call it for every occurence of the same word. For your second example, use `pal_count.setdefault(x, 0)` followed by `pal_count[x] += 1` or `pal_count[x] = pal_count.setdefault(x, 0) + 1`.

Comment: @patrys Sorries... I was just excited that I was actually able to answer something; feel free to flag it.  And thanks for the tip at `pal_count[x] = pal_count.setdefault(x, 0) + 1` - very cool way to solve a common problem.

Comment: if you're using a modern (2.5+) version of Python, you can also use: `pal_count = defaultdict(int)` and then just `pal_count[x] += 1`.

Comment: Oooh [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)!  I've ignored that many times while scanning the docs.  Now you can't flag my answer because there's so much learning going on in the comments :-p

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be much easier for you if your `map()` and `reduce()` input was an actual list of words. To achieve that, `.split()` the string before passing it to `map()`. Then `map()` a word either to itself (if your mapper encounters a palindrome) or `None`. You can then `filter()` the results to discard `None` values, sort it and pass it to `reduce()`. `reduce()` would then reduce it to a `dict` mapping words to their total count.

I will not provide you with a working solution not to take away from the learning factor.

Comment: so basically, the map function will see if any of the words in the list are palindromes. if so then add them to a different list?

    `palindrome = []
    def palindromes(word):
        if (word == word[::-1]):
            palindrome.append(word)
        return palindromes

       map(palindromes, list_of_strings)`

Comment: The philosophy of `map()` is that it will only feed the mapping function with one token at a time and the mapping function should only return one mapped value at a time. Same applies to `reduce()`—it will only pass tokens to reductor one by one. You should not have to maintain your own lists in your mapper / reductor functions. In fact you don't need `filter()` either because reductor can just check for `None` and do ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

For your reduce function, you should start off with an empty dict and update/populate your counts. Reduce functions require 2 parameters, so one can be your dict, and the other, your palindrome. You can feed in an initial value in reduce like so:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, some_list, initial_value_for_x)
```

Take a look at [dict's get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for how to set default values, which should help you simplify your reduce function a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very simple if we decompose the problem into small challenges. In our case this could be:

1. Filter out all the palindromes from the list of words.
2. Get unique words to find the count.
3. Map all the unique words to their appropriate count.

## Code:

```
words =  "bab bab bab cab cac dad"
is_palindrome = lambda word : word == word[::-1]
palindromes = filter(is_palindrome,words.split(" "))
get_count = lambda word : (word , palindromes.count(word))
unique = set(palindromes)
dict(map(get_count,unique))
Out[1]: {'bab': 3, 'cac': 1, 'dad': 1}
```

Here is the short explanation:

```
#Input:
    words =  "bab bab bab cab cac dad"

#Step 1: Filter out the palindromes.
    is_palindrome = lambda word : word == word[::-1]
    palindromes = filter(is_palindrome,words.split(" "))

#Step 2: Get the unique set of string to find their counts.
    unique = set(palindromes)

#Step 3: Map every unique palindrome to their respective count.
    get_count = lambda word : (word , palindromes.count(word))
    dict(map(get_count,unique))

#Output:
    Out[1]: {'bab': 3, 'cac': 1, 'dad': 1}
```

**NOTE:** map in python can accept any sequence, not just list, set or dict. Strings in python are also sequence, hence not satisfied with Cody Hess's statement: map cannot accept strings.

To demonstrate here is the very simple demo:

```
In [10]: map(echo, "python")
Out[10]: ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
```

Answer (score 0):

For map/reduce, using `Counter` object is pretty straight forward.

```
from collections import Counter 
words = "bab bab bab cab cac dad"
words_list = words.split(" ") 
cont = Counter()
for word in words_list:
    cont[word] += 1
print(cont)
# or if you want dict
print(dict(cont))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html